# SQL Concatenate String in Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, string-concatenation

Let's say I have the following query:

```
SELECT anInteger FROM table;
```

How do I make that query concatenate a url on the front - so each row returned becomes:

```
'http://aurl.com/something?q=anInteger'
```

Note it must be the query itself that performs the concatenation - obviously in a situation where you are getting the results into a language you should concatenate in the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would use something like:

```
SELECT 'http://aurl.com/something?q=' + cast(anInteger as varchar) FROM table;
```

Comment: char(number) returns the character from the ascii code passed in as the number argument.  You want `+ cast(anInteger as varchar)`

Comment: Thanks, @Jake, I was just looking into that as you commented. Guess I've been indoctrinated by DB2 :-) Updated to fix.

Comment: Thanks chaps - I used it [very productively](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2319/get-post-with-best-comment-on-site) :)

Comment: @AlexCoplan - In the event of a tie (multiple comments with the same score) this returns multiple records.

Answer (score 6):

It will depend on the RDBMS you are using:

MySQL:

`SELECT concat(anInteger, " your string goes here") FROM table;`

PostgreSQL:

`SELECT anInteger || " your string goes here";`

Oracle:

Same as PostgreSQL

Comment: It's tagged [tag:sql-server].